# Jest doesn't show stack trace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm really confused, in our project jest isn't showing any stacktrace when an error appears.

Following simple failing test:

```
test('XXX', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
});
```

Outputs following:

```html
 FAIL  src/Sulu/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/js/containers/Form/tests/stores/XXX.test.js
  ● XXX

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
    
    Expected value to be:
      false
    Received:
      true
```

That's everything.. No error line.. Nothing..

We have used following things in our setup:

- Jest
- React
- Babel
- Enzyme
- ...

You can have a look here for more details: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/develop/package.json

Someone can get me a hint here?

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/6117

Comment: what's the solution? Update Jest?

Comment: yes, should be fixed with version 23.0.0