# Jest not printing detailed stack trace of failure

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

I have got selenium-webdriver integrated with Jest framework. When there are some failure in selenium, Jest is only printing one line.

> 

```
TimeoutError: Waiting for element to be located By(css selector, *[id="Cell_Navigation"])
Wait timed out after 5186ms

  at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:842:17
```

I tried using something like Error.stackTraceLimit = 100; and "verbose": true. But it is always printing just one line. It will be really helpful if it prints the full stack trace.

Jest Version and Runner

> "jest": "^26.4.2",
> "jest-circus": "^26.4.2"

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't tell you what test failed?

Comment: Yeah it tells me that. But if it prints the full stack trace i can figure where in the test it failed.

Comment: How freakin' big is your test? just look in the test file where it looks for that selector - `Cell_Navigation`. E2E tests are definitely bigger than unit tests, but a single integration test still shouldn't be more than maybe 50-ish lines of code to look at.

Comment: @Adam Its pretty big. There should be something which Jest provides. I am looking for that.

Comment: So doing a search for `Cell_Navigation` in the test that failed yields nothing?

Comment: I do see something related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900741/jest-doesnt-show-stack-trace

Comment: Stack trace is not rendered for promise rejection as per https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5104#issuecomment-381741087. For other failures it will be rendered.

Comment: Take this as a sign - if a stack trace is needed to determine where an e2e test failed, it’s a poorly written e2e test, likely because it’s 1) trying to test way too much or 2) contains too much custom helper/utility code